# Python Numpy: How does numpy.exp(x) coerce the return value of this sigmoid function into an ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking at a preliminary neural network example using the numpy package in python, and I am a little confused about what appears to be some magical type coercion.

Take this sigmoid function as reference, it uses numpy's `numpy.exp(x)` to calculate e to the power of x:

```
def sigmoid(z):
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + numpy.exp(-z))
```

This is very straight forward - it looks like it should return a float, and indeed does so when fed a float or integer as argument:

```
sigmoid(0) # => 0.5
```

What is strange to me is that (according to some footnotes on numpy) when passed a numpy ndarray this function will return a numpy ndarray with the sigmoid function applied to each element:

```
sigmoid(numpy.random.randn(2,2)) # => 2x2 ndarray
```

This makes very little sense to me as the function clearly returns a float divided by a statement containing the numpy functions. How can numpy coerce the return value like this? How is this even possible?

Is their something very strange about python functions that I'm missing? Can numpy somehow change the return property of the function object it executes inside of?

Comment: You should read abiut NumPy universal functions (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) and broadcasting in NumPy. In brief: if `z` is an array, then `numpy.exp(z)` is an array of the same shape, and `1.0+numpy.exp(z)` is also an array of the same shape, etc.

Comment: I am not sure I understood the question 100%, but if you wonder if `1/M` (where `M` is a 2D square matrix) is inverse matrix of `M` then the answer is "no": `1/M` is a matrix whose elements are reciprocals of the the corresponding `M_{i,j}`.

Comment: Unless you use some sort of matrix-specific operations (such as dot-product, cross-product, etc.) most operations on arrays in `numpy` are element-wise. See http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/operations.html for an easy introduction.

Comment: Forget about numpy for a moment, and consider that _all_ Python functions are "generic" by default. If you call `sigmoid` on an int or a float, you get back a float. But if you call it on a complex, you get back a complex. And if you call it on a `str`, `Decimal`, or `Fraction`, you get an exception (for different reasons in each case). And so on. Given that, it should be less surprising that if you call it on an array, you get back an array (of the same shape).

Comment: It's very important to understand that there is *no type coercion going on here*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a scalar, your function returns a float wrapped in a `numpy` type:

```
In [136]: sigmoid(0)
Out[136]: 0.5
In [137]: type(_)
Out[137]: numpy.float64
```

Given an array, it returns an array of the same shape (but float dtype):

```
In [140]: sigmoid(np.arange(3))
Out[140]: array([0.5       , 0.73105858, 0.88079708])
```

`np.exp` does that.

The `+` and `/` produce a `numpy` object if one of the arguments is an `numpy` object.  The interpreter translates the `+` into a call to `__add__` or `__radd__`.  There are various rules when the arguments are different types, but in most cases, if either argument is `numpy` array, the calculation is controlled by the `numpy` version of `__add__`.

So in `1.0 / (1.0 + numpy.exp(-z))`, the `np.exp` produces an array, and the rest of the calculation follows suit.

And the normal behavior of math calculations involving `numpy` arrays is to apply the calculation to each element of the array(s).  We say they operate element-wise.  It gets more complicated when working with several arrays that differ in `shape`; then `broadcasting` rules apply.

There are also `numpy` operations that combine elements of an array, e.g. `np.sum`, and ones that perform more complication combinations like matrix multiplication.

The `math` module version of `exp` only works with Python scalars:

```
In [141]: import math
In [142]: 1.0 / (1.0 + math.exp(-0))
Out[142]: 0.5
In [143]: type(_)
Out[143]: float
In [144]: 1.0 / (1.0 + math.exp(-np.arange(3)))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-144-fa5530a5ba95> in <module>()
----> 1 1.0 / (1.0 + math.exp(-np.arange(3)))

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: Once stated that numpy objects can interact with the interpreter to modify the behavior or the arithmetic operators it makes perfect sense.